# Multiple implementation caused by rvalue parameter

Tags: c++, move

Here is my test code:

```
void test(std::vector<int> vec){};
void test(std::vector<int> && vec){};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    test(v);
    test(std::move(v));

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to call `test(std::move(v))`, I was told `test` is multiply implemented. Obviously I have used std::move making `v` a rvalue. Won't `test(std::vector<int> &&)` be called specifically?

Comment: What does "multiply implemented" mean? And why don't you try it by printing something different in both overloads?

Comment: @Nelfeal printing something in the functions does not change the compile time error: https://ideone.com/6X3Uhf

Comment: @mch Good point. I didn't immediately see what OP's problem was since there was no indication of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't directly related to rvalues, or moving. The same happens with an lvalue reference overload

```
void test(std::vector<int> vec){};
void test(std::vector<int> & vec){};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    test(v); // ambiguous

    return 0;
}
```

The implicit conversion sequences of the two overloads are equivalent. The reason your example only flares up on a move is that the first call passes an lvalue (making the second overload not applicable), while applying `std::move` again produces two equivalent conversion sequences.

Accepting a parameter by value means the argument can be initialized by either a move or a copy. So if you have another overload on a reference (be it rvalue or lvalue), there is  going to be an ambiguity for that value category.