# call of overloaded is ambiguous because of references

Tags: c++, function, reference, overloading, ambiguous

I have this code, which compiles fine:

```
void foo(int x){std::cout << "value copy" << std::endl;} // foo(5) or foo(n)
void foo(int &x){std::cout << "lvalue ref" << std::endl;} // foo(n) only
void foo(int &&x){std::cout << "rvalue ref" << std::endl;} // foo(5) only
```

but since i have referenced versions, it's ambiguous.
how are you meant to use this functionality? i thought the compiler would've gave me an error.

i know we can cast functions, but in that case it'd seem pointless.
you'd might as well call them fooL and fooR if you're just gonna cast right?

Comment: What is ambiguous about it?

Comment: @smac89 try calling foo(0); or foo(n);

Comment: Keep one of the first or third. That's what is causing the ambiguity. In short, remove the first overload

Comment: @smac89 i actually added the 3rd foo just for extra in this question. if i just have int and int& i know i can use foo(0) since there's no ambiguity. but for foo(n) there's still ambiguity. i know i could just have one foo. (a.k.a renaming) but i noticed c++ allows this ambiguous overloading to compile. so this is what i'm asking. how are you meant to even use it?

Comment: @Puddle It's a bit of an Air Bud situation. Nothing in the rules says you are not allowed to create conflicting overloads.That's all there is to it.

Comment: @Frank true. but if anyone does know anymore on this, i just want to know. always stay open to new ideas.

Comment: One thing you should know about about C++ is that the compilers are a bit lazy. They will only complain when you actually attempt to do something illegal. Try actually calling one of the functions and you will start getting compiler errors

Comment: I got started for you: https://wandbox.org/permlink/YPD4tatGdBP6yHWC

Comment: @smac89 that's exactly why i'm here. i know it gives me an ambiguous error. it's in the title.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627939/multiple-implementation-caused-by-rvalue-parameter

Comment: i guess since casting gives you access, that's probably the only reason the compiler doesn't give a conflicting overload error. there's probably no logical situation where you'd want some piece of written code to alternate from referencing to copying. it's possible, but not likely any use for it.

Comment: What's the point of having these three?

Comment: @curiousguy i guess i was just a curious guy too since i thought the compiler would've gave me an error.

Comment: @Puddle Compilers don't have (can't in general) verify that your code is potentially useful. Functions (and function templates) must have different signatures, as the signature is the real "name" of the function (or template). Many overloads are inherently ambiguous: `int f(), f(int=0);` Which `f` is called by `f()`?

Answer (score 1):

During overload resolution, when selecting the best viable function, the compiler will select the overload that has the best conversion sequence.

In the case where the parameters of two compared overload are reference binding, the standard defines what is the best binding according to [[over.ics.rank]/3.2.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.rank-3.2.3) to [[over.ics.rank]/3.2.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.rank-3.2.6). These rule enable the compiler to choose whether `foo(int&)` or `foo(int&&)` is a better match for a given argument type.

But there are no rule that specifies if an argument passed by value is better than an argument bound to a reference parameter. So for this simple case where all overloads takes an `int` either by reference or by value, calling `foo` will always be ambiguous if the argument is not const. (If the argument type is const qualified, `foo(int&)` and `foo(int&&)` are not viable overloads).